# CSS transition not being applied consistently

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to adapt [this CSS menu](https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP) so that it slides from the top of the page when the hamburger is clicked. It slides in as expected on one of the four pages (Page Three in the gif below), but simply appears in place on the other three. However it slides up as expected on menu close.

It gets weird though -- I tried to use Pesticide (the Chrome extension) to look at the element, and when Pesticide is triggered, it works just fine on all of the pages!

[image]

Also I'm using Jekyll but not sure that matters. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

The header component:

```html
<header>
  <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="logo.png" />
    </a>
    <div id="menuToggle">

      <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleMenu();" />

      <div id="hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <ul id="menu" class="uppercase headline">
        <a href="/one"><li>One</li></a>
        <a href="/two"><li>Two</li></a>
        <a href="/three"><li>Three</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The menu sass:

```css
/*
 * Made by Erik Terwan
 * 24th of November 2015
 * MIT License
 *
 *
 * If you are thinking of using this in
 * production code, beware of the browser
 * prefixes.
 */

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

div#menu-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 0 2rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  img#logo {
    height: 12rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 3rem;
  }

  &.visible {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
  }
}

div#menuToggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  right: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  input {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 3.5rem;
    opacity: 0; /* hide this */
    z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  }
}

// * hamburger slices
#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 1;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
    background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease;

  &:first-child {
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  }
  &:nth-last-child(2) {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  }
}

/* 
  * Transform all the slices of hamburger
  * into a crossmark.
  */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ div#hamburger > span:first-of-type {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px, -5px);
}

/*
  * But let's hide the middle one.
  */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ div#hamburger > span:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
  * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
  */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ div#hamburger > span:last-of-type {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

ul#menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */

  transform: translate(0, -100rem);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}

#menu li {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

/*
  * And let's slide it in from the top
  */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

Comment: "but simply appears in place on the other three" what do you mean?

Comment: What exactly the unexpected behavior that happens when "three" is clicked?

Comment: Meaning it doesn't slide in, it just appears where it should be. You can see it at the beginning of the attached gif.

Comment: @MoaazBhnas "Three" is the expected behavior. It's not happening on the other pages.

Comment: if you replace 'transform: none' with a statement that instead explicitly zeroes out every transform, does it still do it?  e.g  transform: translate(0,0) scale(1,1) etc...

Answer (score 0):

This css looks really crooked to me, so I simplified it.
There are also HTML errors on the ul menu

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  background  : steelblue ;
}
menu {
  --menucolors : white;
}
#hamburger {
  display: none;
  }
label[for="hamburger"] {
  display      : block;
  cursor       : pointer;
  float        : right;
  margin-right : 1em;
  }
label[for="hamburger"] span {
  display       : block;
  width         : 1.8em;
  height        : .25em;
  border-radius : .12em;
  background    : var(--menucolors);
  transition    : transform  0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1)
                , opacity    0.55s ease;
  }
label[for="hamburger"] span:nth-of-type(2) { margin: .3em 0; }

#hamburger:checked ~ label[for="hamburger"] span:nth-of-type(1) { transform : translateY(.55em) rotateZ(45deg); }
#hamburger:checked ~ label[for="hamburger"] span:nth-of-type(2) { opacity: 0; }
#hamburger:checked ~ label[for="hamburger"] span:nth-of-type(3) { transform : translateY(-.55em) rotateZ(-45deg); }

menu ul {
  list-style     : none;
  float          : right;
  margin-right   : 2em;
  font-size      : 1.8em;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  transform      : translate(0, -100rem);
  transition     : transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
  }
#hamburger:checked ~ ul {
  transform : none;
  }
menu li {
  display : inline-flex;
  }
menu li a {
  color           : var(--menucolors);
  text-decoration : none;
  border-bottom   : 1px solid transparent ;
  }    
menu li a:hover {
  color               : var(--menucolors);
  border-bottom-color : var(--menucolors);
  }
```

```html
<menu>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
  <label for="hamburger">
    <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
  </label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="/two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="/three">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out!

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't work on the homepage. There must be something else in the code that's interfering. Thanks though, appreciate fixing the errors on the HTML.